# Rest API Postman configuration section cannot be used at this path

Tags: c#, rest, api, postman

I have created a rest API in Visual Studio 2017.  When I use Postman locally, it works great.
I published and tried to consume from another server and received the following error.
This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault=Deny), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode=Deny; or the legacy allowOverride=false
and 
 Config File
 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\API\web.config

I cannot see any issues with the web.config file.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you have access to "ApplicationHost.config" on your server ,If yes, simply set it to "overrideModeDefault" the problem is not with your web.config but your server denied configuration to override by application web.config

Comment: Thank you for your response!.  I accessed the ApplicationHost.Config.  under C:\Users\erobuck\source\repos\WebApi\.vs\config.  I ended up changing all settings to allow but nothing worked...still same error.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: LOL, read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/introduction-to-applicationhostconfig

Comment: I solved this issue.  Here is the post that solved it for me.  Thank you for the help!                                                                             https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFZur.png